# Fast column subset selection

Tags: matlab, cell

What is the fastest way to select for each column a predefined subset and store everything in a cell ?

That means I have a double matrix

```
DAT
```

of dimension n x m

and a selection matrix

```
SEL
```

of dimension n x m. The Matrix 'SEL' is a logical matrix.

Now I want to select for each column of 'DAT' the columns according to 'SEL'.

One possible way is clearly:

```
arrayfun(@(idx) DAT(idx,SEL(idx,:)),(1:n)','uni',false);
```

Is it possibly to speed this up?

Update: 
1. All matrices are sparse
2. n = 1800000, m = 800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be one alternative approach -

```
%// Since we are storing elements from each row, we need to transpose them,
%// so that we could select elements from SEL along the first row, then second
%// row and so on.
DAT_t = DAT.';           %//'
allvals = DAT_t(SEL.');  %//'

%// Create an ID array to be used with ACCUMARRAY later on
cumlens = cumsum(sum(SEL,2));
id = zeros(cumlens(end),1); %// Faster with: id(cumlens(end),1)=0;
id([1 ; cumlens(1:end-1)+1])=1;

%// Finally use ACCUMARRAY for creating cells of output cell array based on
%// IDs from "id" and data from DAT
outc = accumarray(cumsum(id),allvals,[],@(x) {x});
```

Apparently, some quick runtime tests confirm that this proposed approach gives marginal performance boost with really large input datasizes. Thus, with `8000 x 8000` sized input arrays, the runtimes when timed with [`timeit`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) were -

```
time_arrayfun =
    1.5076
time_accum =
    1.4776
```

Also, please note that a considerable amount of time is spent on transposing `DAT` & `SEL` to get `allvals`, as we would only be doing `allvals = DAT(SEL)` in that case. So, if you were storing data from each column instead of each row of `DAT`, the performance boost would be more noticeable!

Comment: @Graph4Me Use `full(allvals)` inside `accumarray`.

Comment: Works, and is 5 sec faster than my approach. (10 sec vs 15 sec)

Comment: There is the signature accumarray(subs,val,sz,fun,fillval,issparse). So may be it is possible to set the issparse flag to 1, without converting to a full matrix ?

Comment: However, I have to run it 4 times (2 different DATA matrices, 2 different SEL matrices). So do you think it can even be improved more?

Comment: @Graph4Me I don't think that usage is meant to use a sparse array as an input, rather whether to output a sparse array or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. For columns:

```
s = bsxfun(@times, SEL, 1:size(SEL,2));
result = accumarray(nonzeros(s), DAT(SEL), [], @(x) {x});
```

For rows, just transpose `DAT` and `SEL`:

```
DAT = DAT.';
SEL = SEL.';
s = bsxfun(@times, SEL, 1:size(SEL,2));
result = accumarray(nonzeros(s), DAT(SEL), [], @(x) {x});
```

Comment: How can I run it when SEL and DAT are sparse?

Comment: @Graph4Me Use `full(DAT(SEL))` inside `accumarray` I think.

Comment: Works, and is 5 sec faster than my approach. (10 sec vs 15 sec)